# JMeter - How to read JSON file?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I used the CSV format for the data files in JMeter. Our VP wants to change the format to JSON. How can I read a JSON file from the disk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

1. Use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and `file` protocol like:

   [image: HTTP Request File Protocol]

   JSON files are basically plain-text files so you will be able to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) to parse JSON data and store the result into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for later reuse

   References:

   - [Jayway JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#getting-started)
   - [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)
2. Use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language. Groovy has built-in JSON support via [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) so you will be able to parse the JSON file programmatically.

   References:

   - The Groovy programming language - [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
   - [Groovy - JSON](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_json.htm)

Comment: Why should I use the HTTP Request sampler for reading a file from the local disk drive?

Comment: Thank you very much, Dmitri. I did not know about *file* option in the HTTP sampler.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this problem is to use `JSR223 Sampler` to read JSON file and load into the `vars` or `props` and use it wherever it is required.

For this,

1. Add a `JSR223 Sampler` in JMeter
2. Add the below code

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.Base64


def propertiesFromMap(map, prefix) {
    for (item in map) {
        id = prefix+item.key;
        if (item.value instanceof Map) {
            propertiesFromMap(item.value, id+".");
        } else {
            value = item.value.toString();
            log.info("Loading property " + id + ": " + value);
            if(value.startsWith("ENC:")) {
                props.put(id, new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.substring(4, value.length()))));
            } else {
                props.put(id, value);
            }
        }
    }
}

def baseDir = org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
def jsonFilePath= baseDir + "/configs/" + "configuration-dev" + ".json";
log.info("Loading properties from " + jsonFilePath);
def jsonMap = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new java.io.File(jsonFilePath));
propertiesFromMap(jsonMap, '');
```

3. Create a directory named `configs` where you placed the `.jmx` file
4. Create a file named `configuration-dev.json` in `configs` directory
5. Add JSON content e.g. in the file:

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "ENC:base64_encoded_value"
   "group1": {
      "grp1_key": "value"
   }
```

6. Access values in Samplers e.g. `${__P(key1)}`, it will return value of `key1`. For `group1` variables access e.g. `${__P(group1.grp1_key)}`
7. For accessing the values into `JSR223` use `props` e.g. `props.get("key1")`
8. You can pass base64 encoded values into JSON by adding `ENC:` as value prefix which will be resolved automatically when accessing values from `props` or `__P()`