# Not able to read json file in JMETER

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to read json's from a text file using below command:

{__FileToString((${JSON_FILE},,)).replaceAll(' ','')}

File not readable.

**Error**: {"timestamp":1586945558777,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Unexpected character ('*' (code 95)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6df97f39; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('*' (code 95)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6df97f39; line: 1, column: 3]","path":"/service"}

I have gone through all related posts too but still not able to find the solution to it. Please can anyone help.

Refereneces:
[JMeter - How to read JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561310/jmeter-how-to-read-json-file)
https://devqa.io/perf/jmeter-send-json-file-as-request-in-body
https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-use-http-request-to-send-multiple-json-files

Thanks, 
Mrinalini

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
${__strReplace(${__FileToString(${JSON_FILE})}, ,,)}
```

You cannot append normal Java functions like [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), if you want to get rid of whitespace characters you need to invoke [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) like shown above (this function is a [Custom JMeter Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin), it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

If you cannot use JMeter Plugins for some reason you can achieve the same using __groovy() function like:

```
${__groovy(new File(vars.get('JSON_FILE')).text.replaceAll(' '\, ''),)}
```

Demo:

[image]